# Проблема с SQL запросами

Tags: sql, sqlite

СУБД DB Browser for SQLite.
У меня есть БД с таблицами: Кинотеатр, Фильм и Показывает.
В таблице "Кинотеатр следующие данные":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице "Фильм":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице "Показывает":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Необходимо сделать следующий SQL запрос: **Выбрать все названия фильмов, которые показываются в сыктывкарских кинотеатрах**

Кодить пытался, куча вариантов не один не помог, подскажите что делать. На этот SQL запрос потратил уже 5 часов... (P.S. Я только учусь)

Comment: у вас есть три таблицы. наверное вы догадываетесь, что надо использовать их в выборке все. Можно с разных сторон к запросу подходить, но проще, наверное, сначала выбрать кинотеатры в сыктывкаре отфильтровав их по where. Далее вам надо присоединить обе оставшиеся таблицы, используя, как вы наверное знаете оператор JOIN, в данном случае INNER  JOIN, указав соответствия ключей. И поскольку в итоге выбрать вам надо названия без повторов, то устроить уникальную выборку с помощью distinct.

Comment: СУБД то какая? Укажите в вопросе

Comment: @Anatoly Я работаю в программе DB Browser for SQLite

Comment: @teran я пытался, у меня ничего не получается. Я может что-то не так делаю, я не понимаю

Comment: @teran И JOIN не получается второй присоединить после первого JOIN

Comment: вот и приведите свой код.

Comment: @teran хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @teran я думаю так, но все равно не верно. Что не так? 
SELECT DISTINCT "Город"
FROM "Кинотеатр" WHERE "Город" = "Сыктывкар"
INNER JOIN "Фильм"
ON "Название" = "Город"

Comment: @Антон [https://habr.com/ru/post/480838/](https://habr.com/ru/post/480838/) прочтите

Comment: @InDevX Сейчас прочту, спасибо. Если возникнут вопросы. Поможете?

Comment: @InDevX Я не понимаю что писать после оператора ON?

Comment: вы сначала разберитесь с тем почему вы пишите `select город` если вам нужны названия фильмов, а не города. И как уже было сказано, что у вас таблицы кинотеатров и городов связываются через промежуточную. Вот сначала надо ее и присоединить, а потом уже фильмы.

Comment: @teran Вы писали: "у вас есть три таблицы. наверное вы догадываетесь, что надо использовать их в выборке все. Можно с разных сторон к запросу подходить, но проще, наверное, сначала выбрать кинотеатры в сыктывкаре отфильтровав их по where" Вот я так и сделал. Выбрал города, и понял что-то не так. И да, вы теперь говорите наоборот

Comment: имелось в виду отфильтровать в where (то есть оставить в выборке только нужные), а не вписать их в select.

Comment: @teran а where пишется же после select. Так что-ли: SELECT "Название" FROM "Кинотеатр" where "Город" IN ('Сыктывкар') ?

Comment: так, но `IN ('...')` тут смысла не имеет, достаточно `= '...'`

Comment: SELECT "Название" FROM "Кинотеатр" where "Город" = "Сыктывкар".
А дальше писать INNER JOIN?

Comment: SELECT "Навзание" FROM "Фильм"
INNER JOIN "Кинотеатр" ON "ID" = "Показывает.Категории кино(Фильм)" 
and "Показывает.Категории кино(Кинотеатр)" = "Кинотеатр.ID" and "Кинотеатр.Город" = "Сыктывкар" Почему не работает?